# make sudoers use their own history file

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, bashrc, bash-history

I just can't seem to get it to work in Ubuntu, it should be a simple answer, maybe someone can help me. All I am trying to do is get a sudoers to use their own history file, but if I set the history var in the `.bashrc` for root with:

```
HISTFILE="/root/.bash_history.$SUDO_USER"
```

nothing seems to happen.

I have tried changing the `/root/.bashrc` and `/etc/skel/.bashrc` with the above entry. Nothing. I have gotten this to work in CentOS before (See [make sudoers use their own history file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223871/make-sudoers-use-their-own-history-file)).

I even moved the entry to the start of the file, as I found some suggestions that stated it may be ignored after a certain point, but regardless of the position, the history files are not being created. If I use my arrow key however the history entries are there... where they come from I have no clue anymore, it seems like some kind of magic, Voodoo it seems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Likely your problem: Ubuntu uses dash and CentOS does use bash.

Comment: Do you run a sudo shell using `sudo -i`? What does `echo $HISTFILE` give when you're in a sudo session?

Comment: I just tried sudo -i and  echo $HISTFILE with output: /root/.bash_history.<username> but the file does not exist. Where in the world is the .bash_history file ???

Comment: `dash` should not come into play here - it is only used as replacement for `bash` when invoked as `/bin/sh`. Interactive shells are not influenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just followed what you described, accompanied by a few experiments

```
~$ sudo -s
~# ls -l $HISTFILE
-rw------- 1 g g 44174 Jan  4 16:26 /home/g/.bash_history

~$ sudo -i
~# ls -l $HISTFILE
-rw------- 1 root root 2356 Jan  4 16:23 /root/.bash_history

~$ sudo ls -l $HISTFILE
-rw------- 1 g g 44174 Jan  4 16:26 /home/g/.bash_history
```

So when we are running standard `sudo` commands **or** when we use `sudo -s` to get a root shell we already are using our own history-file.

Only when we invoke `sudo -i` to get a proper login shell the original root-history is used.

Now I followed your lead and edited `/root/.bashrc` to contain

```
HISTFILE="/root/.bash_history.$SUDO_USER"
```

as first line.

Repeating above experiments with `sudo -s` and `sudo ls -l $HISTFILE` yielded the same results as before (as expected). But `sudo -i` gave me a shell with no history (and no history-file either).

After executing

```
~$ sudo -i
~# ls -l .bash_history*
-rw------- 1 root root 2412 Jan  4 17:16 .bash_history
~# echo $HISTFILE
/root/.bash_history.g
~# ls -l $HISTFILE
ls: cannot access '/root/.bash_history.g': No such file or directory
```

and logging out

```
~$ sudo -i
~# ls -l .bash_history*
-rw------- 1 root root 2412 Jan  4 17:16 .bash_history
-rw------- 1 root root   52 Jan  4 17:25 .bash_history.g
```

I get the expected results (including access to "my" history by using the arrow keys.

Keep in mind that the contents of `/root/.bashrc` are only **executed** for an interactive, non-login shell (like `sudo -s`), for a login-shell (like `sudo -i`) `/root/.bashrc` is only **sourced**, and only if `/root/.profile` contains something like

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
 . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: `sudo ls -l $HISTFILE` doesn't really make sense because $HISTFILE is going to be expanded before actually running the command.